# Anyway to make this discord.js code more compact?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Creating a bot using discord.js called "xok bot" Im using **this** code to set a random number, and the image assigned to that number will be displayed, however after the 30 mark, the code becomes a long, strenuous amount when im sure it can be shortened,

```
exports.run = async (client, message, args, level) => {  
xokNum = Math.round(Math.random()*53)

switch(xokNum){
    case(1):
        message.channel.send({
        files:['D:/XokBotApp/xokBot/xokVariations/resized/xokAngryR.png']
         })
        break
    case(2):
        message.channel.send({
        files:['D:/XokBotApp/xokBot/xokVariations/resized/xokCreepyR.png']
         })
        break;

    case (3):
        message.channel.send({
        files:['D:/XokBotApp/xokBot/xokVariations/resized/xokCursed.png']
         })
         break;
    case (4):
        message.channel.send({
        files:['D:/XokBotApp/xokBot/xokVariations/resized/xokinator.gif']
         })
         break;
    case (5):
        message.channel.send({
        files:['D:/XokBotApp/xokBot/xokVariations/resized/xokLink.png']
         })
        break;
    case (6):
        message.channel.send({
        files:['D:/XokBotApp/xokBot/xokVariations/resized/xokMinion.png']
         })            
        break;
```

ECT

Comment: Refactoring questions generally belong on the Code Review SE. Seems like a simple int => string lookup, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
exports.run = async (client, message, args, level) => {  
const xokNum = Math.round(Math.random()*53);
const messages = {
    1: 'D:/XokBotApp/xokBot/xokVariations/resized/xokAngryR.png',
    2: 'D:/XokBotApp/xokBot/xokVariations/resized/xokAngryR.png',
    3: 'D:/XokBotApp/xokBot/xokVariations/resized/xokCursed.png'
};

message.channel.send({ files: messages[xokNum] });
```

Alternatively you can use an array instead of an object and use the index instead of the key.
**EDIT** If you want to use an array, you need to reduce the index by one like this: `messages[xokNum-1]`

Answer (score 0):

**If** renaming the images is an option you could use string interpolation:

```
message.channel.send({
   files:[`D:/XokBotApp/xokBot/xokVariations/resized/${xokNum}.png`]
})
```

Where your images would be named 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, etc.
Pay attention to the enclosing string characters, the ` character is required.